# Grayscale a Background-image with a transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a website. My Body has a background-image which I want to grayscale after pressing a button. I add the class `.grayscale` to the body which contains a `.grayscale:before`.

```
  .grayscale {
  transition: all 3s;
  position: relative;
}

.grayscale:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  background: inherit;
  transition: all 3s;

  filter: grayscale(70%) brightness(108%);
}
```

The result is as planned, BUT without the transition. The background is in grayscale which is perfect, but because I add the class the transition doesn't count. How is the proper way to handle these situations?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: because your are creating a new element and you cannot have transition on display ... the element should be there initially and then simply add the filter

Comment: But this only works with :before, because otherwise my content gets grayscaled, too. Can I add the :before with javascript?

Comment: yes, that's why the before element should be there intially if you want to have transition .. simply add it to the body and apply the filter using grayscale class later

Comment: What he is saying is that all you need is `body::before` **already in place** with the non-filtered background and then apply the class. That should work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xJryVo

Comment: Thanks that did it!!!